Polynomials that evaluates to squares $\bmod p$ for all big enough prime $p$ is also a square in $\mathbb F_p$
Given an odd prime $p$, we say that a polynomial $f \in \mathbb Z[x]$ has the property $L_p$, if
$ f(m) \text{ is a QR for all $m \in \mathbb Z$} \implies f = g^{2} \text{ in } \mathbb F_p \text{ for some } g \in \mathbb F_p[x]$
(so in particular, if $f$ has a non-QR on its image, then it has $L_p$)
This property is just a local version of the fact that an integer polynomial that outputs only squares is also itself a square of some polynomial.
The question is, is it true for all $n \ge 1$, then we can find a constant $N$ such that all integer polynomials $f$ with $\deg f = n$ has the $L_p$ all $p > N$? If this is not true, can we find a constant dependent on the polynomial?
Edit. I'm very sorry about how my initial nomenclature was confusing, here's what I initially wrote so you can laugh at me

Given a prime $p$ and a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, if it
outputs only square residues in $\bmod p$ (i.e $f(m)$ is QR for all
$m$ integer), implies that $f = g^{2} \text{ in } \mathbb F_p$ for
some $g \mathbb \in \mathbb F_p[X]$, then we say that $f$ is locally
square for $p$. (If a polynomial does not outputs only quadratic
residues, I'll still refer to it as locally square)

The answers are very useful in any case, and in fact shows that if $f$ outputs only square residues for infinitely many large primes, then it is a square. An polynomial version of Q1 given in the first answer.

Thanks, I'll learn how to make better questions.

Adding one more candidate for the intended question to the nice list Qiaochu Yuan posted.

Assume that the degree of the polynomial $f(x)\in\Bbb{F}_p[x]$ is $n$, and that $f(x)$ is not a square. If we further assume that $p$ is large enough (approximately $p>n^2$ will do), then it follows that some of the values of $f(x)$ are not quadratic residues modulo $p$.
This follows from the Weil bound on character sums. Particular for the quadratic character aka Legendre character aka Legendre symbol
$$\eta:\Bbb{F}_p\to\{0,-1,+1\}\subset\Bbb{Z}$$
defined by
$$
\eta(x)=\begin{cases}+1, &\ \text{if $x$ is a non-zero quadratic residue modulo $p$,}\\ 0, &\ \text{if $x=0$},\\
-1, &\ \text{if $x$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $p$.}
\end{cases}
$$
In that case the Weil bound says, that if $f(x)$ has $m$ (distinct!) zeros in the algebraic closure $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$ (so $f$ is squarefree, and $m=\deg f$, then
$$
\left\vert\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_p}\eta(f(x))\right\vert\le (m-1)\sqrt p.
$$
If all the values of $f(x)$, $x$ ranging over the prime field, were squares, then the sum on the left would be equal to $|p-N|$, where $N\le m$ is the number of zeros in the prime field. A comparison with the Weil bound implies $|p-N|\le (m-1)\sqrt p$ then forces $m$ to be large enough, roughly $>\sqrt p$.

I don't have a good idea how tight this bound is in general. It is easy to find polynomials of the form $f(x)=x^{(p-1)/2}+a$ taking only square values. That's because
$x^{(p-1)/2}$  only ever takes values $0,\pm 1$. Meaning that if we find three consecutive quadratic residues $a-1,a,a+1$ (probably exist for all large enough $p$), we are in business. That is, assuming $a\neq0$ when the roots of $f(x)$ are simple. Examples:

$x^3+1$ modulo $p=7$ takes only values $0,1$ and $2=3^2$,
$x^5+4$ modulo $p=11$ takes only values $3=5^2$, $4$ and $5=4^2$.

Of these the cubic modulo $7$ is the lowest degree possibility, because we can complete any quadratic to a constant times a square + another constant, which won't do. There may be a lower degree example for $p=11$, but I don't have the time to search for one systematically.

I don't think you've asked the question you've meant to ask; as written what you're asking for is much too strong, and already the polynomial $f(x) = x$ is a counterexample; it's not locally a square $\bmod p$ for any prime $p$.
The question I think you intended to ask is some variation of the following questions (but I can't tell which):

Q1: Is it true that if an integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is a square $\bmod p$ for all primes $p$, or sufficiently large primes $p$, then it's a square in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Yes, and it suffices to ask for sufficiently large primes $p$. This follows from the Grunwald-Wang theorem; IIRC this case has a reasonably elementary proof using quadratic reciprocity, and you may or may not have to use Dirichlet's theorem. As a last-ditch resort, this definitely follows from the Frobenius density theorem applied to the polynomial $f(x) = x^2 - n$.

Q2: Is it true that if a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ only takes on square values $\bmod p$ for all $x \in \mathbb{F}_p$, then it's a square in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ ?

No. For example, $f(x) = x^p - x$ only takes on the value $0 \bmod p$ for all $x \in \mathbb{F}_p$, but if $p$ is odd it can't be a square (and it's not a square when $p = 2$ either).

Q3: Is it true that if a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ takes only square values $f(k)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, then it's a square in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Yes. This is Theorem 4 in Ram Murty's Polynomials assuming square values which also discusses the multivariate case. The argument is pretty straightforward; I found it discussed on math.SE here by Andrew Dudzik.
Note that by Q1 this condition is equivalent to the condition that for all $k$, $f(k) \bmod p$ is square for all sufficiently large primes $p$.

Q4: Is it true that if a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a square polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ for all primes $p$, or sufficiently large $p$, then it's a square in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Yes. This in particular implies that $f$ takes on square values $\bmod p$ for sufficiently large primes $p$, so it follows from Q1 + Q3. Likely there is an alternative direct argument.

sorry, I'll add some clarification, but for the question I'm currently asking, the identity is not a counterexample because the condition of locally square would vacuously hold for any prime, as it does not outputs only quadratic residues for any odd prime.

@Curious: it is incredibly confusing to use "locally a square" to refer to a condition which is not equivalent to being locally a square!

Yeah, I was made aware of that, thanks in any case, I'm sorry for the inconvenient
